# [Errno 30]Read-only file system: '/target/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic'

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, read-only

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and I am trying to install 14.04 on my laptop. The laptop wasn't really working and only boots with Ubuntu CD. I don't care for any files or anything on the computer, I just want to get a working system installed on my computer. When trying to install Ubuntu I get:

The installer encoutered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 30]Read-only file system: '/target/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic'

This is often due to a faulty hard disk. It may help to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the hard drive is fine (no problems in the past, taken good care of) it is likely because you had an error burning the disk or downloading the image. Redownload the installation ISO and burn it to a fresh disk and try again

Comment: I tried that and still didnt work

Comment: and i'm not sure if the hard drive is completely fine.

Comment: if it ever had a severe impact, this error means replace it and backup before it crashes, then

Comment: I have now encountered a different message saying "errno 2 no such file or directory '/target/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24'" in which i posted in another question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: if I addressed the issue you had, could you mark the question as solved to clean thing up a bit?

Comment: Well I still haven't gotten it to install

Comment: yeah, I looked at the bug reports for that error and it points directly to a faulty hard drive, sorry dude you have to replace the drive itself

Comment: it's not able to read basically any actual data from the beginning sectors of the disk, basically rendering it unbootable no matter what

Comment: Would you be able to link me to those reports please. And is there any way to allocate space to at least save files or what not while running the live CD?

Comment: look up the error you got the second time along with the first, the first few results on google point to hard drive failure. If you're asking how to reuse the disk for data, my answer is don't it is having trouble with reading basically anything from the disk, so data recovery is your issue now, try and get the data off the disk and then recycle it.